# Why do regex patterns result in "bad string" errors in jsonschema?

Tags: json, regex, schema, jsonschema

I'm using a regex to validate a property, in json schema.

The schema is as follows:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema",
    "$id": "http://example.com/example.json",
    "type": "object",
    "required": [
        "library_version"
    ],
    "properties": {
        "library_version": {
            "$id": "#/properties/library_version",
            "type": "string",
            "title": "Library version",
            "description": "The library version (e.g. 0.0.1) used to create this file.",
            "pattern": "^(0|[1-9]\d*)\.(0|[1-9]\d*)\.(0|[1-9]\d*)(?:-((?:0|[1-9]\d*|\d*[a-zA-Z-][0-9a-zA-Z-]*)(?:\.(?:0|[1-9]\d*|\d*[a-zA-Z-][0-9a-zA-Z-]*))*))?(?:\+([0-9a-zA-Z-]+(?:\.[0-9a-zA-Z-]+)*))?$",
            "message": {
                "required": "Library version is a required property",
                "pattern": "The version must be a semantic form, like 0.0.1 (see https://semver.org/)"
            },
            "examples": [
                "0.0.1"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Where the big regex is for a [semver - c.f. here](https://semver.org/).

Using [jsonlint](https://jsonlint.com/) I get:

```
Error: Parse error on line 14:
...le.",            "pattern": "^(0|[1-9]\d*)\.(0|[
----------------------^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got 'undefined'
```

Surely I don't have to escape regex patterns in json schema? Strings should be treated as literals, right? Does anyone know what on earth is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use certain characters without escaping, even in literal strings: https://www.freeformatter.com/json-escape.html

Your regex needs to have all backslashes escaped (you can do this using the tool at the link).

Comment: ermahgodd. Because the regexes aren't crazy enough already. Useful escaping tool, though. Thank you Oli!

Comment: This is a requirement of JSON and indeed Javascript strings, not anything specific to JSON Schema. If you were using Javascript to create your schemas, you could use the `toString` method on a regular expression: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/toString